# Reveal highlight in RevealBackgroundBrush doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-c#

I try use RevealBackgroundBrush, but Reveal Highlight doesnt work.

RevealBorderBrush hightlight is work.

RevealBackgroundBrush in sdk style work too (for example "ButtonRevealStyle"), but if i copy ButtonRevealStyle in app resources and apply style for button RevealBackgroundBrush doesnt work.

I reinstalled windows, and try use brush in another uwp projects, but is doesnt work

**I try use CSharp code:**

```
private void RevealGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var grid = sender as Grid;
  grid.Background = new RevealBackgroundBrush() {
    Color = Color.FromArgb(80, 0, 0, 0),
    TargetTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light,
    AlwaysUseFallback = false
  }; // grid.background
}
```

**And i try use Xaml:**

```
<Grid Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="RevealGrid_Loaded" >
   <Grid.Background>
      <RevealBackgroundBrush AlwaysUseFallback="False" TargetTheme="Light" Color="#33818181" />
   </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

**Details:**

- Visual Studio 2019
- SDK 10.0.18362.0
- Windows 10 Pro 1903 (18362.239 build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RevealBackgroundBrush` is a dynamic effect and does not exist independently. In other words, the `RevealBackgroundBrush` depends on the **state**.

The simple Grid has no state, so the `RevealBackgroundBrush` doesn't work, but we can use the Grid as a Template container for stateful controls, like Button:

```xml
<Button Content="Yo!">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" Width="100" Height="100">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <RevealBackgroundBrush/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>

</Button>
```

We use `VisualStateManager` for state management and adjust the state of Reveal.

The same reason can be applied to other controls.

Best regards.

Comment: How can I do this programmatically?